# Javac fails to compile inner class with an inner class but works when the class is moved to its own code file - why?

Tags: java, javac

I have encountered a peculiar build situation where a java project compiles in eclipse but fails on the build machine (Ant 1.8.2 with JDK 1.6)

The compile fails on a class called 'DestinationList', which is an inner class with an inner class. Structure is similar to below.

```
public class MappingDetail {

    public class DestinationList extends AbstractGrowingScrollTable {

        public class DestinationListRow {

        }
    }
}
```

With the classes laid out as above, the compilation fails complaining it cannot find 'AbstractGrowingScrollTable'. If I remove the inner-inner class 'DestinationListRow' the compile succeeds. If I move 'DestinationList' to its own code file compilation also succeeds.

What is going on here? Since I have a work-around I ask out of interest. I cannot understand why this would fail.

'AbstractGrowableScrollTable' is in a separate jar, but this jar is definitely on the classpath and in fact with verbose logging turned on I can see the class is actually found by javac shortly after. Excerpt below. Note on the last list of the log it does load AbstractGrowableScrollTable.

```
[javac] C:\Work\Decisiv\BUILD_AREA\code\source\APEI01\com\initech\sd\ap\ei01\ui\MappingDetail.java:551: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class AbstractGrowingScrollTable
[javac] location: class com.initech.sd.ap.ei01.ui.MappingDetail
[javac]     public class DestinationList extends AbstractGrowingScrollTable {  
[javac]                                          ^
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\ks\ta01\resource\IResourceable.class(com\initech\sd\ks\ta01\resource:IResourceable.class)]  
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\rt01\resources\Resources.class(com\initech\sd\za\rt01\resources:Resources.class)]  
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\sh01\shared\Pair.class(com\initech\sd\za\sh01\shared:Pair.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\CheckBox.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component:CheckBox.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\Grid.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component:Grid.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\Image.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component:Image.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\Label.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component:Label.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\Row.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component:Row.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\layoutdata\GridLayoutData.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\layoutdata:GridLayoutData.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\layoutdata\RowLayoutData.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\layoutdata:RowLayoutData.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\properties\Alignment.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\properties:Alignment.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\properties\Font.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\properties:Font.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\table\ScrollTableColumn.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\table:ScrollTableColumn.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\table\ScrollTableRow.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\component\table:ScrollTableRow.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\resource\DefaultStyle.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\resource:DefaultStyle.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\za\ui\resource\ImageResources.class(com\initech\sd\za\ui\resource:ImageResources.class)]
[javac] [loading com\initech\sd\ui\cf\AbstractGrowingScrollTable.class(com\initech\sd\ui\cf:AbstractGrowingScrollTable.class)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a compiler bug.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6707323